# Automatically find installation directory of application and run batch command inside folder

Tags: windows, command-line, batch

Basically, assume I have program called `ABCD` installed.

I want to automatically find out where exactly (which folder) it is installed (sometimes not installed in C drive, that's why), and run a batch file command inside that folder.

An idea I'm having is to check for the name in control panel programs list automatically, but I don't know how.

Comment: Is `abcd.exe` in your `PATH`? Does it create anything in the registry?

Comment: I'm just wondering if it's possible to grab directory from control panel programs list.

Comment: As for registry key is placed or not, idk, but I don't wish to rely on registry only.

Comment: Grabbing something from the control panel programs list requires digging in the registry.

Comment: Well if the registry does have such a list, then I'd have to use it.

Comment: So you need to look in your registry and see what info is available. Then I can write a batch file for you. Can you share what the real name of the program is?

Comment: Adobe Acrobat Pro DC

I'm just configuring some options using batch file

Comment: Ah. I don't have it installed so I can't figure out the registry entries.

Comment: well im still installing it and configuring it, but i know the key is at: 

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Adobe\(product name)\(version)\`

Comment: 32 bit key is at HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Adobe\(product name)\(version)\

Comment: I have to go eat. I will come back to this a bit later. The key should have a `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Adobe\...\InstallPath` which contains the install directory.

Comment: ok thanks. im also thinking is it possible for PowerShell instead?

Comment: I have provided a solution for `Acrobat Reader` (which I have installed). You should be able to tweak it for `Adobe Acrobat Pro DC`

Answer (score 3):

#### Is there a way to dynamically determine where Adobe Acrobat Pro DC is installed?

I don't have `Adobe Acrobat Pro DC` installed but here is a batch file that determines where `Adobe Acrobat Reader` is installed.

You should be able to modify this to find `Adobe Acrobat Pro DC` instead.

The following batch file (`test.cmd`) will determine where Adobe Reader is installed and sets the `_acrobat_path` environment variable to this value:

```
@echo off
setlocal
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "usebackq tokens=3*" %%a in (`reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Adobe\Acrobat Reader\DC\InstallPath" /s`) do (
  set _acrobat_path=%%a %%b
  echo !_acrobat_path!

  )
endlocal
```

Example output:

```
F:\test>test
C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat Reader DC\Reader
F:\test>
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [for /f](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) - Loop command against the results of another command.
- [reg](http://ss64.com/nt/reg.html) - Read, Set or Delete registry keys and values, save and restore from a .REG file.